# How to select a contact using KeyboardButtonRequestPeer in a Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon

I'm working on a Telegram bot, and I'm trying to implement the functionality to select a contact using the KeyboardButtonRequestPeer feature. However, I'm encountering some issues with my current approach.

[Select a Recipient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWCq.jpg)

[After click "Select a Recipient"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77lmT.jpg)

Here's what I've tried so far: click(share_phone=True)

The bot responds with the following data:

```
[Message(id=471025, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=6343432495), date=datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 7, 16, 20, 53, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='(Select a contact from the keyboard below)', out=False, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False, pinned=False, noforwards=False, from_id=None, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=None, reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(rows=[KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonRequestPeer(text='Select a Recipient', button_id=123, peer_type=RequestPeerTypeUser(bot=None, premium=None))])], resize=False, single_use=True, selective=False, persistent=False, placeholder=None), entities=[], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None, reactions=None, restriction_reason=[], ttl_period=None), total=104]
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently, we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @Lonami I'm using session + telethon to interact with the bot but the bot asks to invite 1 friend from my contacts, I don't know how to use telethon to handle such action.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Official clients probably use https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/get_contacts.html to get the list of contacts and then send one. But I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem still. You should update your question with more details and not use screenshots.